# Device Driver Signing on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, digital-signature

I am not Windows users so I need some help with driver digital signature enforcement in windows 10 64 bits.

1) I have device driver which according Windows 10 doesn't have digital signature.

When I go to device properties in control panel, and go to Driver Tabs , next to Digital Signer , it says "Not digitally signed"

But when I click on Driver Details, look at all the Driver Files, all of them have Digital Signer. So I don't understand inconsistency.

2) When I examined driver signature for individual driver files, I noticed they are signed with SHA1. But they were signed before 2016. I am not sure if Windows 10 is rejecting signature because it is SHA1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I go to device properties in control panel, and go to Driver Tabs , next to Digital Signer , it says "Not digitally signed".  But when I click on Driver Details, look at all the Driver Files, all of them have Digital Signer. So I don't understand inconsistency.

It's due to the fact the driver was sigend with a SHA1 code signing certicate.  As of July 2019 Windows does not trust SHA1 code signing certificates.

> When I examined driver signature for individual driver files, I noticed they are signed with SHA1. But they were signed before 2016. I am not sure if Windows 10 is rejecting signature because it is SHA1.

Even if Windows still trusted SHA1 certificates out of the box, a certificate signed in 2016, would not be explictly trusted due to expiration of said certificate.

You can either add the certificate to your trusted certificate store or disable driver signature enforcement all together.  **I do not suggest you disable the enforcement of signed drivers.**

> In support of our promise to provide best-in-class security to our customers, Microsoft are planning to discontinue support for SHA1 code signing certificates

Source: [Preparing for the deprecation of SHA-1 signatures](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/announce/sha1deprecation)